# Fetch Content from A Div id using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php

I have following html code

```
<div id="b_changetext" class="FL gL_13 PT15"> <span class="gr_15 uparw_pc"><strong>5.80</strong></span> (+2.28%)</div>
```

I wanted to extract content (+2.28%)
 Tried following code

```
foreach($html->find('div[n_changetext]') as $e){
      echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
    echo "wwwwww";
}
```

On running it does not enter the for loop . ( "wwwwww" is not displayed)

Can anyone please suggest a solution

Comment: find('div#n_changetext') you can use dash for id selector and dot for a class

Answer (score 1):

`div[n_changetext]` finds elements with an `n_changetext` attribute (which is not valid in HTML).

To find an element with a given id you must specify that the name of the attribute is `id` and specify the value.

The value, in your example, starts with a `b` not an `n`:

```
find('div[id=b_changetext]')
```

Comment: I have changed to find('div[id=b_changetext]') as you suggested but still it does not work. It does not enter the loop.

Comment: @kiranshiv — https://i.imgur.com/12NGsHH.png — Your code (with my modification) works fine when I test it.

Comment: <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$html = str_get_html('http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/construction-contracting-real-estate/dlf/D04');


foreach($html->find('div[id=n_changetext]') as $e){
      echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
 echo "wwwwww";
 
}


echo "ssssssssssss";
?>

Comment: `str_get_html` expects to be passed a string of HTML, not a URL.

Comment: There's an example on the homepage of the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser site!

Comment: I have even tried $html = file_get_html('http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/construction-contracting-real-estate/dlf/D04'); but does not work. Is there any problem with HTMl source file